# Visual Studio stating "Microsoft is not a class or namespace name"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and developing in C++.

I have installed Microsoft Cognitive services by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/setup-platform?tabs=dotnet%2Cwindows%2Cjre%2Cbrowser&pivots=programming-language-cpp) walkthrough and my pakcages.config looks correct.

Now when following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=script%2Cbrowser%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-cpp#install-the-speech-sdk) tutorial to use cognitive speech, my c++ solution will not build stating "Microsoft is not a class or namespace name"

This shows the error and the sample code and the packages.config file

[code and error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyyGQ.png)

[packages.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N98z.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question include your code and error messages **in the question itself as text**, not images

Comment: I wouldn't call the page you link to _a tutorial_.  They are code snippets that don't compile, alone.  Consider their [C++ quickstart samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/quickstart/cpp/windows) to see complete code that can compile.

Comment: You are missing some include. The only include you have is the iostream header and that has nothing to do with `Microsoft::CognitiveServices::Speech`

Comment: Looks like `#include <speechapi_cxx.h>` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you could add `speechapi_cxx.h` in `Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories`.

The path is `cognitive-services-speech-sdk-master\quickstart\cpp\windows\from-microphone\packages\Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.1.15.0\build\native\include\cxx_api`.

[image]

Also, you need to add the code `using namespace Microsoft::CognitiveServices::Speech::Audio;`.

Here is the complete code：

```
#include <iostream>
#include <speechapi_cxx.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Microsoft::CognitiveServices::Speech::Audio;
using namespace Microsoft::CognitiveServices::Speech;
auto config = SpeechConfig::FromSubscription("real_sub_id", "region");
int main()
{

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    auto audioCofig = AudioConfig::FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
    auto recognizer = SpeechRecognizer::FromConfig(config, audioCofig);
    cout << "Speak " << endl;
    auto result = recognizer->RecognizeOnceAsync().get();
    cout << "RECOGNIZED: Text=" << result->Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the library you are using, but i am sure that you need to `#include` something before you can actually use the library.